# Buffer to integer. Having trouble understanding this line of code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking for help in understanding [this line of code](https://github.com/watson/hash-index/blob/master/index.js#L16) in the npm moudle [hash-index](https://github.com/watson/hash-index/blob/master/index.js#L16).

The purpose of this module is to be a function which returns the sha-1 hash of an input mod by the second argument you pass.

The specific function in this module that I don't understand is this one that takes a Buffer as input and returns an integer:

```
var toNumber = function (buf) {
  return buf.readUInt16BE(0) * 0xffffffff + buf.readUInt32BE(2)
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why those specific offsets of the buffer are chosen and what the purpose of multiplying by `0xffffffff` is.

This module is really interesting to me and any help in understanding how it's converting buffers to integers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It prints the first UINT32 (Unsigned Integer 32 bits) in the buffer.

First, it reads the first two bytes (UINT16) of the buffer, using Big Endian, then, it multiplies it by 0xFFFFFFFF.

Then, it reads the second four bytes (UINT32) in the buffer, and adds it to the multiplied number - resulting in a number constructed from the first 6 bytes of the buffer.

Example: Consider [Buffer BB AA CC CC DD ... ]

```
0xbb * 0xffffffff = 0xbaffffff45
0xbaffffff45 + 0xaaccccdd = 0xbbaacccc22
```

And regarding the offsets, it chose that way:

First time, it reads from byte **0** to byte **1** (coverts to type - UINT16)

second time, it reads from byte **2** to byte **5** (converts to type - UINT32)

So to sum it up, it constructs a number from the first 6 bytes of the buffer using big endian notation, and returns it to the calling function.

Hope that's answers your question.

[Wikipedia's Big Endian entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Big-endian)

**EDIT**

As someone pointed in the comments, I was totally wrong about 0xFFFFFFFF being a left-shift of 32, it's just a number multiplication - I'm assuming it's some kind of inner protocol to calculate a correct legal buffer header that complies with what they expect.

**EDIT 2**

After looking on the function in the original context, I've come to this conclusion:

This function is a part of a hashing flow, and it works in that manner:

Main flow receives a string input and a maximum number for the hash output, it then takes the string input, plugs it in the SHA-1 hashing function.

SHA-1 hashing returns a Buffer, it takes that Buffer, and applies the hash-indexing on it, as can be seen in the following code excerpt:

```
return toNumber(crypto.createHash('sha1').update(input).digest()) % max
```

Also, it uses a modulu to make sure the hash index returned doesn't exceed the maximum possible hash.

Comment: Left shift 16 bits would be equivalent to multiplying by `0x10000`.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Good catch, I got totally confused - at this point I can only assume it's some inner protocol of them to generate the number - maybe a checksum number or something a like?

Comment: Maybe it will make more sense as `(uint << 32) - 1`?  Just a thought

Comment: That's one way to achieve this number, but question is, what's the actual meaning behind this number? this can be only answered in a wider context of the program (i.e - seeing the flow in which this function is used)

Comment: Ok, this is just my theory, but if the buffer contents are being summed in 6 byte chunks and written into the same buffer, you could avoid counting the sum bytes (those first six) by subtracting them from the total sum from the buffer.  Perhaps they are combining the shift and subtract?

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication by 2 is equivalent to a shift of bits to the left by 1, so the purpose of multiplying by 2^16 is the equivalent of shifting the bits left 16 times.

Here is a similar question already answered:
[Bitwise Logic in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911216/bitwise-logic-in-c)

Comment: Isn't `0xFFFFFFFF` 32 bits?

Comment: Indeed it is. The variable in the original question is only 16 bits wide however